# VisualSVN on Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-virtual-machine, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

Any one have a idea about setup visual svn on microsft azure and access it through different macine?

- I just add Azure VM and Inbound and Outbound port set to 8443 and same port i used for visualsvn.but i cannot access it through different macine.

I cannot use Classic VM on My Azure.
My Previous azure had classic vm but new portal i doesn't have classic vm it redirect to normal vm as below image.

Comment: Why can't you access it? Are you getting a specific error message? Does your computer hang? Do you become overwhelmed by wails of the undead?

Comment: I have followed same steps as above link describe.I can logged in to browser on azure vm.
But I cannot logged in using my local macine.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Do you have any experience regarding that visualsvn on azure vm?
Because I cannot find right resource regarding that one.at least a video on youtube.all of them are explain in local server configuration

Comment: You use classic VM or ARM mode VM? You need open port 8443 on Azure NSG/Endpoint and Windows Firewall.

Comment: @TDM Hi, does it work now, you use classic VM?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT - My old azure portal had classic vm. But new portal it doesn't have classic vm. It redirects to vm normal one.I already add that vm image also.please check that one.

Comment: @TDM You need open port 8443 on Azure NSG, then you could access it with Public IP. `<resource group>--><VM NSG>--><Inbound rule>`.

Comment: @TDM Your VM is ARM mode VM not classic VM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155056/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-tdm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, you need open port 8443 on Azure NSG(Inbound rule). By default, it only creates port 3389, you need add a new rule.

[image]